# Is There a Good Way to Change Many Joined Meshes in Order to Make One Mesh With No Inside?

Tags: workflow, retopology

I'm attempting to kitbash a number of different models together to make a new one. The problem that I now have a lot of badly joined together meshes. Ideally, what I would like to do is to join them on the correct vertices (So I can do things like sculpting). Also, it would be great if it removed all of the vertices which were inside the model.

Is there anything we can do to do this automatically, like a plug-in or some other  option? Or do I need to do this by hand?

Answer (score 1):

No garantee it will work but you could try to boolean.

First make sure you don't have holes, select all in *Edit* mode and *Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes* (set the values in the *Operator* box):

[image]

[image]

Then select all your meshes except one and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)*, and again choose the right settings in the *Operator* box. If the meshes are closed it should delete all inner vertices:

[image]

[image]